# Storing and retrieving enums from NSArray

Tags: objective-c

I'm a beginner obj-c programmer. I want to store enums in an NSMutableArray, then retrieve them.
I do this by first converting the enum to NSNumber object then storing that object into the array, and then retrieving it and converting it back to an integer. I have code that does it without arrays, and works, but I need to use an array.

Code:

```
//What I am trying to do:
        NSNumber *n = [NSNumber numberWithInt:west];
        [DirectionList addObject:n];
        Direction intendedDirection = [[DirectionList objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
        if (intendedDirection == west)
        {
            exit(-1); // DOES NOT EXIT, BUT SHOULD
        }

//This code works, though
        NSNumber *n = [NSNumber numberWithInt:west];
        Direction intendedDirection = [n intValue];
        if (intendedDirection == west)
        {
            exit(-1); // EXITS AS EXPECTED
        }
```

Any ideas why the 1st one doesn't work?
Thanks.

Comment: did u create (alloc/init) a NSMutableArray?

Comment: Wow I can't believe I actually forgot to do that. That solved it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Note that you should not use variable names with leading upper case.  Those should be reserved for class names.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to mutate the array, I suggest you this method which is much, much cleaner than the one you're trying to follow.

I'm using `NSString` for this example but you can use any object you want

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, Direction) {
    North,
    South, 
    West, 
    East
};

NSString *const directionDescriptions[] = {
    [West] = @"West",
    [East] = @"East",
    [North] = @"North",
    [South] = @"South", 
}
```

Then you can access your description using the enum as the index of this array.

```
// E.g.
NSSLog(@"%@", directionDescriptions[West]); // @"West"
```